# Search function won't display

Tags: c#, sql, search, datagridview

I am trying to implement a search function using a textbox that would display into a datagridview. I wanted it to be so that no matter which column im trying to search for, be it from the Project Name, or location, it will display in the datagridview. However, the datagridview wont change when i type something into the textbox. Thanks a bunch. Here is the code:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Project "+"WHERE(ProjectName LIKE @Search)"+ " OR(NumberOfUnits LIKE @Search)"+ "OR(Location LIKE @Search)";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HAZWAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=wantest2;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + er.ToString());
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE] and [edit] code accordingly... It's very unclear what you expect to happen with the DB query where you completely ignore results... as well as ` dataGridView1.DataSource = null`...

Comment: Try setting any "unspecified" field values to % before the AddWithValue() statements.

Comment: Where are you expecting the results to come from? You are calling ExecuteNonQuery which wont return a result set.  I think there are some missing details here. Also you are calling BindGrid() after setting the DataSource to null. is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some element or line of code are missing while you bind GridView.

You have to use [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8) to pull the data from database and store into [DataSet](http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataset/csharp-dataset-sqlserver.htm) or [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) for further process which here is bind with gridview.

try below code:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE ProjectName LIKE @Search OR NumberOfUnits LIKE @Search OR Location LIKE @Search";
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HAZWAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=wantest2;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");

                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                        //Instead of above method you have to use 
                        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        da.Dispose();
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException er)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                        MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data. DETAIL: " + er.ToString());
                    }             

                }
            }
```

you can wrap above code in One Method like `RefreshGrid` or `BindGrid` etc. and call that method based on the requirement.

Comment: omg this works! sorry about the vagueness of the question. Very new to programming. I just followed along with youtube tutorials and filled in the blanks.